# Re-route traffic to an alternative outbound IP address

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have an application running on Alpine that makes requests to a particular IP address/port, say 127.1.1.1:10000. I'm unable to change that particular IP address/port. The service that it is trying to reach is at another IP address/port, for example 216.58.193.64:80 (an address for Google's home page).

I'm looking for a way to redirect traffic outbound requests from 127.1.1.1:10000 to the actual address, 216.58.193.64:80. This redirect is two-way - that is, the application makes requests and expects responses.

Graphically, I have

```
 Alpine (with --cap-add=NET_ADMIN)
 IP assigned
 ╔════════════════════════════════════╗             ╔══════════════════╗
 ║                                    ║             ║                  ║
 ║  ┌──────────────────────────────┐  ║  -request-> ║ Remote           ║
 ║  │ Application                  │  ║             ║ service          ║
 ║  │ requests at 127.1.1.1:10000  |  ║             ║ at               ║
 ║  └──────────────────────────────┘  ║  <-reply-   ║ 216.58.193.64:80 ║
 ║                                    ║             ║                  ║
 ╚════════════════════════════════════╝             ╚══════════════════╝
```

I tried using iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --destination 127.1.1.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 216.58.193.64
```

iptables, which when queried contains only the OUTPUT

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7 packets, 345 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       10   586 DNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            127.1.1.1            to:216.58.193.64
```

I then tried as a baseline

```
curl 216.58.193.64
```

which replies with

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

However, when I try

```
curl -v 127.1.1.1
```

then curl does not return and there is no output. It stops after reporting:

```
curl -v 127.1.1.1
*   Trying 127.1.1.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

I have also tried POSTROUTING

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --destination 127.1.1.1 -j SNAT --to-source 216.58.193.164
```

but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

@ibrahim is partially correct, but apparently incomplete.

From https://serverfault.com/questions/247623/iptables-redirect-local-connections-to-remote-system-port, the following works

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type LOCAL -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 216.58.193.164
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL --dst-type UNICAST -j MASQUERADE

sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

I can then run:

```
curl 216.58.193.164:10000
```

and get the correct result.

It is also important to note that when run in a container, you need to start the container with `--privileged`

Answer (score 0):

Nat is disabled for lo addresses as default. You need to enable it by

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

Also add it to /etc/sysctl.conf to make it permanent.